# How am I going wrong in glMultiDrawArraysIndirect function?

Tags: python, numpy, opengl, pyopengl

I'm programming using Python and Modern OpenGL, and I tried to implement the `glMultiDrawArraysIndirect` function in my code to draw a simple shape, I want to apply it later on to a more complex thing, but this is just a simple test that I don't know exactly where the error is.

```
import glfw, time, ctypes, math, pyrr
import numpy as np
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GL.shaders import *

glfw.init()

glfw.window_hint(glfw.SAMPLES, 4)

w = glfw.create_window(640, 480, "Galeria das Sombras", None, None)

glfw.make_context_current(w)

v = """
#version 430
in layout(location=0) vec3 posicao;
in layout(location=1) vec2 textura;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform vec3 def;
uniform vec3 pos;
uniform vec3 scale;
uniform float giro;
uniform float giro2;
out vec2 texcords;
void main(){
    texcords = textura;
    vec3 p = vec3(posicao.x*scale.x,posicao.y*scale.y,posicao.z*scale.z);
    p = p+def;
    p = vec3(-sin(giro)*p.z+cos(giro)*p.x,p.y,sin(giro)*p.x+cos(giro)*p.z);
    p = vec3(p.x,-sin(giro2)*p.z+cos(giro2)*p.y,sin(giro2)*p.y+cos(giro2)*p.z);
    p = p+pos+vec3(gl_InstanceID,0,0);
    gl_Position = view*vec4(p,1);
}
"""

f = """
#version 430
in vec2 texcords;
uniform vec3 cor;
uniform sampler2D texinfo;
void main(){
    gl_FragColor = vec4(cor,1)*texture(texinfo,texcords);
}
"""

shader = compileProgram(compileShader(v,GL_VERTEX_SHADER),compileShader(f,GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER))

tudo = [-1,-1,0,0,1,
        1,-1,0,1,1,
        1,1,0,1,0,
        -1,1,0,0,0]

tudo = np.array(tudo, np.float32)

VBO = glGenBuffers(1)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO)
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, len(tudo)*4, tudo, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

'''
tudo = [[1,1,0,3],[2,2,1,3]]

tudo = np.array(tudo, np.uint8)

VBI = glGenBuffers(1)
glBindBuffer(GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER, VBI)
glBufferData(GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER, len(tudo)*4, tudo, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
'''

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 20, ctypes.c_void_p(0))
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)

glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 20, ctypes.c_void_p(12))
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)

glUseProgram(shader)

view = pyrr.matrix44.create_perspective_projection_matrix(60, 640/480, .1, 1000)
p = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "view")
glUniformMatrix4fv(p, 1, GL_FALSE, view)

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE)
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)

from PIL import Image

t = glGenTextures(1)
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, t)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
buffer = Image.open("p.jpg")
data = buffer.tobytes()
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, buffer.size[0], buffer.size[1], 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data)

girar = 0
tempo = glfw.get_time()
tfps = glfw.get_time()
fps = 0
action = 0

while not glfw.window_should_close(w):
    glfw.swap_buffers(w)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    view = pyrr.matrix44.create_perspective_projection_matrix(60, glfw.get_window_size(w)[0]/glfw.get_window_size(w)[1], .1, 1000)
    p = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "view")
    glUniformMatrix4fv(p, 1, GL_FALSE, view)
    glViewport(0,0,glfw.get_window_size(w)[0],glfw.get_window_size(w)[1])
    p = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "cor")
    glUniform3f(p, 1, 0, 0)
    p = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "def")
    glUniform3f(p, 0, 0, 0)
    p = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "scale")
    glUniform3f(p, 1, 1, 1)
    p = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "giro")
    glUniform1f(p, girar*math.pi/180)
    if glfw.get_time() - tempo > 1/60:
        girar+=1
        tempo = glfw.get_time()
        if action > 0:
            action-=.05
        if action < 0:
            action = 0
    p = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "giro2")
    if glfw.get_key(w, glfw.KEY_W) and action == 0:
        action = 2
    if action > 1:
        glUniform1f(p, (1-(action-1))*-90*(math.pi/180))
    else:
        glUniform1f(p, action*-90*(math.pi/180))
    p = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "pos")
    glUniform3f(p, 0, 0, -10)
    glMultiDrawArraysIndirect(GL_TRIANGLES, np.array([[0,3,1,0],[1,3,1,1]]), 2, 1)
    fps+=1
    if glfw.get_time() - tfps > 1:
        print("FPS:",fps)
        fps = 0
        tfps = glfw.get_time()
    glfw.poll_events()
    if fps > 400:
        time.sleep(.01)

glfw.destroy_window(w)
glfw.terminate()
```

In the VBO there is a square, but I was going to draw only 2 triangles using the first 3 points and then the last 3 next to each other, I didn't find many examples of this type of code on the internet, only `glMultiDrawArraysIndirect` documentation but I couldn't do it run in my code, at least not without giving a good lock, when I change the `drawcount` for 1 wheel but nothing appears on the screen.

There is and the `drawcount` I took from the site: http://docs.gl/gl4/glMultiDrawArraysIndirect

I tried to change the `indirect` value for different types of numpy arrays, with different `uint` `dtypes` but most of them either error or run without anything appearing on the screen does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: The values you're trying to put into your _draw indirect_ buffer don't make the slightest sense, how did you come up with those numbers?

Comment: based on guesswork and google translate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify the NumPy array you need to specify the type `uint32`. The last argument (*stride*) is specifies the distance in basic machine units between elements of the draw parameter array (16 bytes):
(see [`glMultiDrawArraysIndirect`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glMultiDrawArraysIndirect.xhtml))

```py
indirect = np.array([[3, 10, 0, 0], [3, 5, 1, 0]], dtype=np.uint32)
glMultiDrawArraysIndirect(GL_TRIANGLES, indirect, 2, 16)
```

or

```
glMultiDrawArraysIndirect(GL_TRIANGLES, indirect, 
    indirect.shape[0], indirect.dtype.itemsize * indirect.shape[1])
```

The above code does the same as:
(see [`glDrawArraysIndirect`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawArraysIndirect.xhtml))

```py
indirect1 = np.array([3, 10, 0, 0], dtype=np.uint32)
glDrawArraysIndirect(GL_TRIANGLES, indirect1)
indirect2 = np.array([3, 5, 1, 0], dtype=np.uint32)
glDrawArraysIndirect(GL_TRIANGLES, indirect2)
```

Respectively the same as:
(see [`glDrawArraysInstancedBaseInstance`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawArraysInstancedBaseInstance.xhtml))

```py
glDrawArraysInstancedBaseInstance(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3, 10, 0)
glDrawArraysInstancedBaseInstance(GL_TRIANGLES, 1, 3, 5, 0)
```

---

When you use `glDrawArraysIndirect` or `glMultiDrawArraysIndirect`, you need to create the following data structure:
(see [GLAPI/glMultiDrawArraysIndirect](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GLAPI/glMultiDrawArraysIndirect))

```cpp
typedef  struct {
    uint  count;
    uint  instanceCount;
    uint  first;
    uint  baseInstance;
} DrawArraysIndirectCommand;
```

This can be achieved using a NumPy array with the data type `uint32`:

```py
np.array([count, instanceCount, first, baseInstance], dtype=np.uint32)
```

Comment: A doubt, originally I wanted to draw several different 3D models as if they were an instance where I would modify their positions using Vertex Shader, is this possible using this function?

Comment: @ArthurSally You asked how to use `glMultiDrawArraysIndirect`. I've answered your question well. What do you mean by "several different 3D models"? If you want to draw different mesh at the once, you need to put all of the vertices in one buffer. `glMultiDrawArraysIndirect` is meant for drawing many instances of the same mesh. Furthermore _glMultiDraw**Arrays**Indirect_ is of the _Draw**Array**_ family not of the _Draw**Element**_ family. Hence you can't use indices.  I don't think the function does what you want, but I don't think I understand exactly what you want.

Comment: @ArthurSally Possibly you are searching for [`glMultiDrawElements`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glMultiDrawElements.xhtml) or [`glMultiDrawElementsIndirect`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glMultiDrawElementsIndirect.xhtml)